# accessing twitter streaming api using node js

Tags: node.js, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

Hi I am trying to access the twitter rest api 
https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json
I am using nodejs.

For authentication I have used ntwitter. Authentication is 
going through fine. I get the success message.

But once it passes authentication it is not displaying tweets.
it  shows something like.

```
----------------------------------------
o/p
----------------------------------------------------------------
tweet[object Object]
success
tweet[object Object]
tweet[object Object]
tweet[object Object]


My prog
-------------------------------------

var twitter = require('ntwitter');
var https = require('https');


var twit = new twitter({
  consumer_key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  consumer_secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  access_token_key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  access_token_secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
});

twit.verifyCredentials(function (err, data) {
    console.log("success");
  });


twit.stream('statuses/filter', {track:'manipal'}, function(response) {
          var body ='';
              response.on("data",function(chunk){
               //var tweet = JSON.parse(chunk);
                console.log("tweet" + chunk);
              });

              response.on("end",function(){
                console.log('Disconnected');
              });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [ntwitter test suite](https://github.com/AvianFlu/ntwitter/blob/master/test/memory.js), it seems the tweet object has the properties text and user. So if you do `console.log("tweet: " + chunk.text)`, you might have more success.

Answer (score 0):

By using string addition you are converting the tweet object into a string representation. Because it has no toString() method, it outputs to the console as [object Object].

Try either `console.log(chunk);` or `console.log("tweet "+chunk.text);`